# peerjs webrtc call response

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc

I am using peerjs server and peerjs to makewebrtc call between 2 peerid. The call is like

```
 var call = peer.call($('#callto-id').val(), window.localStream);
```

establishment is working perfect. Now i have added a popup when incoming call is coming from other peers.The pop is asking "Recieve the call?"

If user press "yes" from popup call recieve using 
      'call.answer(window.localStream);'
 else 
   no action

If the user reject the call the caller not getting any response that the call is recieved or not.

How i can understand the call is recieved or not by calling
' var call = peer.call($('#callto-id').val(), window.localStream);'

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I realize this reponse is mad late... but I just stumbled upon your question and figured I can help you out, if you already have a solution then that is cool, this will help if anyone else asks later.

The line of code you are looking for on the receiving end (person being called) is...

```
call.close(mediaStream);
```

This should be executed when the user rejects the call. Then you should have a function which handles that and displayed whatever HTML you want to your caller.

You will need to use a flag for this, as you will want a different result for the close function if the call was answered first beforehand as this would imply a normal call went ahead.